# In IDA freeware, how to create a new database in IDC and load a file into it?

Tags: ida, malware, disassemblers, firmware-analysis, idc

I have IDA freeware version 5 and version 8, v5 is running on wine, v8 is directly on kali OS, and I am trying to create an IDC script to generate asm+lst files for all files in a certain folder.

What I have so far is a script that gets a list of files from an input folder and saves the list into a file, then I read the file line by line for each input file I want to process. My problem comes here, It seems I can't use `loadfile()` when I do not have a database opened, ready to receive the file, and when I try to load the file with a database opened and a loaded file I don't get any result back!

- Is there a way to create an empty database via IDC script (free version)?
- Is it even possible to process a large number of files in a folder programmatically one by one without using command line switches, as it seems I can't get IDA freeware to recognize any of the switches I use in the Kali terminal?
- I am not even sure that I am using the correct arguments for the loadfile() function, if I want to load the whole file, what should I fill in as the pos parameter? 0?
- And for the size how do I get file size from within IDC script?

Any answer to those questions would help greatly.